# Menu become fix header on scroll but under header images

Tags: menubar

My Menu from [my site](http://abrotrans.ro) become fixed header scroll, but he scrolled under the pictures in the header menu. How to make the menu to get over these pictures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the css `z-index` property on your `#menu` element.

```
#menu {
  z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: I have more one problem. This page (http://abrotrans.ro/ruta/planificator-ruta.htm) have another .css file but i have added same codes for menu but dont work.

Comment: The second page seems really different when looking at the source code. Are you sure all the javascript and css used in the first page for the menu are present in the second one?

Comment: I solved the problem thanks. I used too many versions of jquery and i have deleted some.